# Displaying data with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, listview, datagrid

I have a tbl_categories and a tbl_items. I want to display tbl_categories in a horizontal manner and list objects from tbl_items vertically below each category name. I am confused how to get all this data using TSQL stored procedures and displaying them using ASP.NET native controls.

Columns with headers of category names. rows of items keyed with category_id.

The db is set up correctly. It is the ASP.NET controls I have trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a Repeater myself, and make it output an HTML Table. The categories row would be in the `HeaderTemplate`, the closing tags in the `FooterTemplate`, and the actual data inside the `ItemTemplate`

http://blogs.sitepoint.com/asp-net-repeater-control/

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is to setup business objects which support the data in a way you wish to present it, which may not always be the way it is handled by your database.
Then you can use those objects directly to bind or feed data into the UI.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Pivot to do that. See this referece http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx